# Laravel - How to link data from drop down table into another resource model

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, model

I have a `Profile.php` model, where `state_id` is saved from the `states` table. How do I link the states table to the profile instance which is returned in json.

`{ "profile_id" : 1, "state" : {state data} }`

The state data should contain the specific state model for the `state_id` stored for the profile model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering two models respectively - `Profile` and `State`, then a relationship like following could be structured -

**Inside the Profile model -**

```
/**
 * Get associated state for the profile.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\belongsTo
 */
public function state()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
}
```

**Inside State model -**

```
/**
 * Get associated profiles for the state.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\hasMany
 */
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Profile::class);
}
```

**Query:**

`$profileWithState = Profile::with('state')->get();`

Comment: Thanks for this answer, the with method worked great.